# Is it possible to infer $v$ from divided summations?

Tags: summation

I have a problem. I worked on it for some time and I've got this:
$$\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n/2} v^{2k}}{\sum_{k=0}^{n/2} v^{2k+1}}=\frac{1}{2}$$
The only thing we know about $n$ is that it is even.

Is it possible to infer $v$ from this? If not, I guess I'll have to approach the problem in different way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since$$\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n/2} v^{2k}}{\sum_{k=0}^{n/2} v^{2k+1}}=\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n/2} v^{2k}}{v\sum_{k=0}^{n/2} v^{2k}}=\frac1v,$$you can infer that $v=2$.

Comment: @Hanlon If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: Yeah, I planned to do so. I couldn't do it right away so I went on to do something else and forgot to accept your answer.